# Using bisect to combine numbers in two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, bisection

In the following two lists

```
l1 = [10, 33, 50, 67]
l2 = [7, 16, 29, 55]
```

the goal is to combine the closest numbers in a dict,and the combination have to stop once it reaches the last item in the second list, so in this case if there are items not combined in the first list, these items will not be considered, so the output of the above lists will be

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 55
67 ->---   # in this case because the last n. in the first list(55) is identified, so the n.67 will be zero
```

this code gives the following output

```
for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    ind -= abs(l2[ind-1] - s) < l2[ind] - s
    print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
```

the output

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 55
67 -> 55 ### here is the error, so here will be: 67 -> --, because, 55 is identified in the previous items.
```

The statement

```
if ind == len(l2) - 1: 
    break
```

gives this output

```
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
```

Can someone help?

Comment: The `hi=len(l2) - 1` is redundant, as that is the default for that argument.

Comment: You'll get the same problem with `[10, 33, 34, 50]`, only `33` and `34` will both be mapped to `29`. What should happen in that case?

Comment: You already stated how to solve this; you say that *the combination have to stop once it reaches the last item in the second list*. So simply test `if ind == len(l2) - 1: break` to end the loop.

Comment: Put that **after** printing the 50 -> 55 output...

Comment: Like this: https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/6f3f74c4204eb2fd0f92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to terminate the loop when the last index of `l2` is reached, then simply use `break` when that condition is met:

```
for s in l1:
    ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
    ind -= abs(l2[ind-1] - s) < l2[ind] - s
    print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
    if ind == len(l2) - 1: break
```

This produces the output you desire for your sample input:

```
>>> for s in l1:
...     ind = bisect(l2, s, hi=len(l2) - 1)
...     ind -= abs(l2[ind-1] - s) < l2[ind] - s
...     print("{} -> {}".format(s, l2[ind]))
...     if ind == len(l2) - 1: break
... 
10 -> 7
33 -> 29
50 -> 55
```